# Proplem Convert array to string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I try converting array to string with PHP but it not work and show notice:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\test2.php on line 5
```

Something wrong? And this is my code:

```
<?php 
     include("config/dbconnect_acc.php");
     $query = mysql_query("select id from users") or die(mysql_error());
     while($row[]= mysql_fetch_array($query));
     $data = implode(",",$row);
     echo $data;    
?>
```

when i `print_r($row)` it show result as format:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 581 ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 42325 ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 21975 ) [3] => Array ( [id] => 60327 ) [4] => Array ( [id] => 113788 ) [5] => Array ( [id] => 63282 ) [6] => Array ( [id] => 85149 ) [7] => Array ( [id] => 40737 ) [8] => Array ( [id] => 28508 )
```

But i want as this format:

```
(581,42325,21975,60327...)
```

How should I do? Please help me! Thanks all!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
     include("config/dbconnect_acc.php");

     $query = mysql_query("select id from users") or die(mysql_error());    

     $arr = array();    

     while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query))
     {
        $arr[] = $row['id']; 
     }

     $ids = implode(",",$arr);
     echo $ids;    
?>
```

`$arr[] = $row['id'];`  consider this line.

Comment: @mrdragon Is it work for you?

Comment: yes, it worked very well

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php 
     include("config/dbconnect_acc.php");
     $query = mysql_query("select id from users") or die(mysql_error());    

     $finalValues = array();    

     while($row= mysql_fetch_array($query))
     {
        $finalValues[] = $row[0]; 
     }

     $data = implode(",",$finalValues);
     echo $data;    
?>
```

Also, consider using *mysqli* or *PDO* instead. The regular *mysql* driver you're using is deprecated. Good luck!

Comment: Try dumping the first row, replace everything inside the while loop with : _var_dump($row);die();_  What do you get ?

Answer (score 0):

Try get this in query:
`select concat(id,',') as ids from users`

Comment: While this may be a valid option (there are plenty), it doesn't solve the original problem as described

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is with `mysql_fetch_array($query)` as it returns arrays and not strings. So `$row` is full of arrays each with one element rather than strings as you are expecting. Converting the returned array form `mysql_fetch_array($query)` into a string type before adding into `$row` should fix your issue.

References:
https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php